# Set AutoScaleGroup Desired Capacity using variable from witihin loop

Tags: bash, aws-cli

I am running the below script which gets the names of stacks filtered by the name Test.

I can output the current capacity, max and min values, I can echo the name of the scale group as loops through ang gets the values, 
but cannot seem to set the desired capacity on the $group variable, I keep receiving null values, I've tried a couple of variations but all return null.

Command

```sh
read -p 'Enter Name Where Scaling Groups will be updated: "Default Stack" = ' -e -i 'Test' stackname \ 

scalegroups=($(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query 'AutoScalingGroups[?contains(Tags[?Key==`aws:cloudformation:stack-name`].Value, `'$stackname'`)].AutoScalingGroupName')) \
echo "Total Stacks Found :" ${scalegroups[*]} \
for group in "${scalegroups[@]//,/}" \

do 
    currentcapacity=$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query 'AutoScalingGroups[?AutoScalingGroupName==`'$group'`].[DesiredCapacity]' --output text) \
    echo $group 
    aws autoscaling set-desired-capacity --auto-scaling-group-name $group --desired-capacity $((currentcapacity + 1)) --honor-cooldown \
    latestcapacity=$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query 'AutoScalingGroups[?AutoScalingGroupName==`'$group'`].[DesiredCapacity]' --output text) \
    echo "Latest Capacity = " $latestcapacity \
done
```

Error

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the SetDesiredCapacity operation: AutoScalingGroup name not found - null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say because your script has quite a number of syntax errors in it, at least as far as what you have pasted in here.

I fixed up the script so that it works as apparently intended. I changed it to this:

```sh
echo -n 'Enter Name Where Scaling Groups will be updated: "Default Stack" = ' -e -i 'Test ' ; read stackname

scalegroups=($(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups \
  --query 'AutoScalingGroups[?contains(Tags[?Key==`aws:cloudformation:stack-name`].Value, `'$stackname'`)].AutoScalingGroupName' \
  --output text))

echo "Total Stacks Found :" ${scalegroups[*]}

for group in "${scalegroups[@]//,/}"
do 
  echo "Processing group: $group"

  currentcapacity=$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups \
    --query 'AutoScalingGroups[?AutoScalingGroupName==`'$group'`].DesiredCapacity' \
    --output text)

  aws autoscaling set-desired-capacity \
    --auto-scaling-group-name $group \
    --desired-capacity $((currentcapacity + 1)) \
    --honor-cooldown

  latestcapacity=$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups \
    --query 'AutoScalingGroups[?AutoScalingGroupName==`'$group'`].DesiredCapacity' \
    --output text)

  echo "Latest Capacity = " $latestcapacity
done
```

A few points:

- I think your bug was probably in the scale groups line. You were missing `--output text`.
- Note I made it more readable using line breaks (the `\` character).
- I removed superfluous coercing of `DesiredCapacity` to an array `[DesiredCapacity]`.

Comment: Thanks Alex , Still getting used to formatting. apologies. , the --output text has assisted, I've also amended as recommended and receiving the correct output now.